# Python: Screen Scraping table values

Tags: python, selenium, screen-scraping

I am currently using Python 2.7 with Selenium and beautiful soup 4 installed.

I'm creating a script that is navigating through pages of tables. In the table, each row has a link that takes me to another page, which I can scrape as a form. Is there a way I can pull the values of one column (there is only one column in the table) and store them as an array?

This way, I can cycle through the array to navigate each of the links.

Thanks!

Comment: Which website are you scraping?

Answer (score 0):

try using `driver.find_elements_by_css_selector()` so you'd do something like:

```
tds = driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("#your-table-id td")
```

`tds` will now be a list of element objects. Note this will give you all tds in the table.